# Animate view from outside of bounds to show partly then full

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I am currently struggling to find a good way how to animate some views in a specific way.
Following screenshots should show what I want to achieve:

### First state (HIDDEN):

[image: First state (HIDDEN)]

### Second state (COLLAPSED)

[image: Second state (COLLAPSED)]

### Third state (EXPANDED)

[image: Third state (EXPANDED)]

The change between these states should be animated. 
Those views are not draggable or slideable at all.
I know that there is the SlidingUpPanel by umano but I think that would be kind of an overkill.

At the moment the way I achieve this behaviour is the following:
I wrap the 2 panels (top and bot) in a relative layout and use the property animator to animate a change of the height of the relative layout.
So when the state is COLLAPSED then the height of the relative layout will be animated from 0 to the height of the top panel.

This works fine but I think that this is a really bad way to do this.
I already tried out to create a custom ViewGroup but the animating part didnt work yet.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use FrameLayout here as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/top_panel_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_panel_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, create enum for states

```
enum State {
    HIDDEN {
        @Override
        public void moveTo(View topPanel, View bottomPanel, long animationDuration) {
            topPanel.animate().translationY(topPanel.getHeight()).setDuration(animationDuration);
            bottomPanel.animate().translationY(topPanel.getHeight() + bottomPanel.getHeight()).setDuration(animationDuration);
        }
    },
    COLLAPSED {
        @Override
        public void moveTo(View topPanel, View bottomPanel, long animationDuration) {
            topPanel.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(animationDuration);
            bottomPanel.animate().translationY(bottomPanel.getHeight()).setDuration(animationDuration);
        }
    },
    EXPANDED {
        @Override
        public void moveTo(View topPanel, View bottomPanel, long animationDuration) {
            topPanel.animate().translationY(-bottomPanel.getHeight()).setDuration(animationDuration);
            bottomPanel.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(animationDuration);
        }
    };

    public abstract void moveTo(View topPanel, View bottomPanel, long animationDuration);
}
```

Usage of this would be as follows:

```
State newState = State.EXPANDED;
newState.moveTo(topPanel, bottomPanel, 200);
```